# Indesign script list all authors from metadata in an alert

Tags: javascript, metadata, adobe-indesign

I want to list all authors that are stored in the metadata in an alert message (As a finishing alert after they were added via a script). But my script always only shows the first entry. The names are separated by a semicolon in the document info.

I wrote the following script with the help of chatGPT. (I'm still a beginner in scripting but I'm learning a lot with it.)

Does anyone know how to access all entries?

```
// Load the XMP Toolkit library
ExternalObject.TI = ExternalObject.TI || {};
ExternalObject.TI["AdobeXMPScript"] = "XMPScript";

// Get the XMP metadata of the current document
var xmp = app.activeDocument.metadataPreferences;

// Get the document title from the XMP metadata
var docTitle = xmp.documentTitle;

// Get the dc:creator values from the XMP metadata
var creatorString = xmp.author;
var creators = creatorString.split(";");

// Remove any extra whitespace or semicolons from each creator name
for (var i = 0; i < creators.length; i++) {
  creators[i] = creators[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

// Create a message with the document title and the list of creators
var message = "Document title: " + docTitle + "\nCreators:\n";
for (var i = 0; i < creators.length; i++) {
  message += "- " + creators[i] + "\n";
}

// Display the message in an alert box
alert(message);
```

Edit: Since I already got the one minus point here (I assume because of the use of ChatGPT): I worked on that script for hours. I didn't just put in information and got it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xmp = app.activeDocument.metadataPreferences;
var ns = 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/';
var num = xmp.countContainer(ns, 'creator');
var creators = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    creators.push(xmp.getProperty(ns, 'dc:creator[' + i + ']'));
}
alert('Creators:\n' + creators.join('\n'));
```

Or this (about the same approach):

```
var xmp = app.activeDocument.metadataPreferences;
var ns = 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/';
var creators = [];
var i = 1;
while (с = xmp.getProperty(ns, 'dc:creator[' + i++ + ']')) creators.push(с);
alert('Creators:\n' + creators.join('\n'));
```

Comment: OK - why? Care to explain your answer at all to add some reasonings?

Comment: Let the author of the question confirms if my code works and accepts it first.

Comment: Both of your methods worked. Thank you so much. Could you explain how? Or do you know why mine only gave me the first author name?

Comment: The property `xmp.author` contains only first value indeed. I think it's a bug of the API. There is nothing we can do about this. But there is the workaround via the `getProperty()` method, etc. The `xmp` data is a XML-like structure and you can parse it to a degree. If you open the 'RAW' view mode in the File>Info dialog window you will see the structure and there are some 'paths' ('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/', etc) and the elements ('creator', for example). You can count the elements, read them, create or delete elements, get or set its values. Unfortunately all this barely documented.

Comment: As for the alert window in your script, it sounds weird. But I'm not exactly an expert in changing metadata, I can only try to guess a solution if you show what your script looks like.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did try using getProperty() but couldn't make it work. I didn't know about push(). 
Regarding the alert. I deleted my message before I saw there where answers. I could fix it. I used my variable for documentTitle instead of the variable that had set the title. So the alert used the title before it was set. I still don't get why but at least it worked. I had to use your while-loop though for the authors to update. It's a workaround. That way it doesn't really pick the set documentTitle and author but the value that is set as it. (if that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what the problem. If you want to see the `documenTitle` property in the alert window probably it can be done if you change the last line with this: `alert('Document title: ' + xmp.documentTitle + '\nCreators:\n' + creators.join('\n'));`

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem is that it's only showing the metadata of title and author that is set before the rest of my script that sets the metadata runs through. So if there is no metadata before the script runs, the alert is empty. If i run the script a second time, the alert shows the authors and title since the first application of the script set them. 
But anyway. I'm fine with it working using the variable that is used to set the documentTitle content. Although I really am curious as to why the alert comes before the rest of the script is applied.